# Why should I decrease the input signal frequency when increasing the FFT size

Tags: signal-processing, fft, vivado

I have a dds compiler with an IFFT block. The objective is to compute an IFFT of size 2048 of IQ data generated from dds
Configuration of DDS compiler:
System clock frequency=30 MHz, phase width=12, phase data= 64.
Using this configuration, the dds generates a 0.4675 MHz sine cos
Configuration of IFFT target clock frequency=30 MHz, target data throughput=30 MSPS.
When I try to compute a small IFFT of (8,16,32) of the generated signal from the dds compiler, the result of computation is correct compared to Matlab.
The problem is when I increase the size of IFFT (64,128, 256,1024,2048), I have incorrect results. I don’t know why? Or I respected the Nyquist theorem (0.4675 MHZ< sampling frequency of IFFT/2=30/2). I cannot properly configure my dds to compute an IFFT of size 2048.  by increasing the size of the FFT, I should decrease the output frequency of the dds which correspond to the input data of the IFFT but  I dont know why? A priori there is something I cannot understand. I am very grateful if you can respond me. Please any clarification.

Comment: Just a thought: maybe this is a memory issue? Larger (I)FFT sizes require multiple transform stages---when the size is larger than the largest codelet, which is plausibly 32. It is useful for speed to do stages out of place, rather than in place, but that requires more memory. Check your FFT documentation about whether it wants extra workspace buffer space for larger FFT sizes.

Comment: Thanks you for you reponse. I dont think that the problem concern the ram. A priori, it has not related to decrease the freqeuncy of my input signal but the generated signal